# Vue Multiple Conditions with Boolean

Tags: vue.js

I have this Vue code which is currently working.

```
<template lang="pug">
  ReuploadHeader(v-if="isReupload")

    SubmittedPendingReupload(v-if="status === 0 && isReupload")              
    SubmittedPending(v-if="status === 0")                  
</template>
```

The problem is it does not reach `SubmittedPendingReupload` component although the status is 0 and `isReupload` is true. Instead, it goes to `SubmittedPending` and `ReuploadHeader`

I console.log to troubleshoot and I can see `Progress status: 0` and `Reupload status: true`

```
<script>
  export default {
  ...mapState('abc', [
    'status', 'reupload'
  ]),
    computed: {
      isReupload() {        
        console.log('Progress status: ' + this.status);
        console.log('Reupload status:' + this.reupload);
        return this.reupload;
      }
    },
</script>
```

Comment: `progressStatus` not `status` ?

Comment: sorry, it is progressStatus in Production but I updated the variable name here for brevity

Comment: So in this case, you want all three components to be loaded ?

Comment: Where is `reupload` declared? Is it reactive? In the template you could just do `v-if="status === 0 && reupload"`, there's no need for a computed

Comment: @Psidom, I want only `ReuploadHeader` and `SubmittedPendingReupload` to be loaded

Comment: `SubmittedPending(v-else-if="status === 0")` ?

Comment: @coyotte508, `reupload` is from state.